# Шифрование и дешифрование

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!
Я зашифровал файлы, расположенные на диске, но дешифровать их хочу не на диск, а в память. Возможно ли такое, если возможно можете дать подсказку?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать MMF (memory mapped file). Эта технология позволяет писать (читать) данные в файл как в память.

Answer (score 1):

Можно считать данные в память, а затем расшифровать эту память. Однако если цель - защитить данные, нужно иметь в виду следующее:

- расшифрованный файл в памяти уязвим и может быть восстановлен с помощью дампа,
- C# - интерпретируемый язык, поэтому исполняемая сборка по сути содержит исходный код и анализ этого кода может быть использован для извлечения алгоритма расшифровки и восстановления с его помощью файла.

Answer (score 1):

Смотреть на данную задачу можно с разных сторон. Мне видится вот так, что если файл хочется расшифровать куда-то, но не на диск, то можно сделать это на виртуальный диск, который находится в памяти компьютера. Тема для поиска: ramdrive.